# Equation with $\text{Li}_2$ has a unique solution

Tags: calculus

Let $c \geq 0$ and $y \in [0,1]$, I would like to show that $$c^2\text{Li}_2(y)=\log^2(1-y),$$ has a unique solution $y=y(c).$  Here $\text{Li}_2(y)= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{y^n}{n^2}$ is the dilogarithm.

I was unable to do this by taking a few derivatives, as one finds that neither $\frac{d}{dy} c^2\text{Li}_2(y)-\log^2(y),$ nor $\frac{d^2}{dy^2} c^2\text{Li}_2(y)-\log^2(y)$ is always positive regardless of $c$.

The equation is also equivalent to $$c^2\int_0^y \frac{-\log(1-z)}{z} dz = \left(\int_0^y \frac{1}{1-z}dz\right)^2,$$ and $$c^2y +\sum_{n \geq 2} y^n \left(\frac{c^2}{n^2} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{1}{n-i}\right)=0.$$

Of course, $y(0)=1^-$, but I haven't been able to show that the general case has a unique solution.

Comment: You mean one solution apart from the obvious solution $y=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(y)=\log^2(1-y)$ and $g(y)={\rm Li}_2(y)$. Clearly $g(0)=f(0)=0$ and  $g'(y)=-\frac{\log(1-y)}{y}>0$ on $(0,1)$. Using the "L'Hospital monotone rule" the function $h:y\mapsto f(y)/g(y)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ if the function $y\mapsto f'(y)/g'(y)=2y/(1-y)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$, and this is true.

So, $h((0,1))=(0,+\infty)$. Thus, for very $c\in(0,+\infty)$ there exists a unique $y(c)\in (0,1)$ such that $h(y(c))=c^2$. Done.

The simplest proof of the "Hospital monotone rule" can be found in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1460) as lemma 2.1 by Omran Kouba.

Comment: See page 14 of this: http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/121/publn121p11-24.pdf